# Как поменять местами текст и картинку?

Tags: android, java

Это верхнее меню, первоначально было просто на button и не было проблем, переделал для land режима и пришлось переделывать его. Вопрос в следующем, как поменять местами, что бы вначале была картинка, а под ней текст. Вот код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include layout="@layout/title" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_button"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/homeButton"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_home_g" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/homeButtonText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    style="@style/buttonFont"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
                    android:text="@string/str_base_activity_toolbar_home" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/assignedButton"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_trailer_inspection_g" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/assignedButtonCounter"
                    style="@style/buttonBadge"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@id/assignedButton"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@id/assignedButton"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/assignedButtonText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    style="@style/buttonFont"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/str_base_activity_toolbar_assigned" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/availableButton"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_available_g" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/availableButtonCounter"
                    style="@style/buttonBadge"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@id/availableButton"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@id/availableButton"
                    android:text="2234"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/availableButtonText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    style="@style/buttonFont"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/str_base_activity_toolbar_available" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/completedButton"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_completed_g" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/completedButtonText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    style="@style/buttonFont"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/str_base_activity_toolbar_completed" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.2" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/mailButton"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_mail_g" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/mailButtonCounter"
                    style="@style/buttonBadge"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@id/mailButton"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@id/mailButton"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:visibility="gone" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/mailButtonText"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    style="@style/buttonFont"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:text="@string/str_base_activity_toolbar_mail" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/parentLinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_main"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

вот кусок кода который интересует:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.2" > 

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" > 

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/completedButton"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_completed_g" /> 
    </RelativeLayout> 

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/completedButtonText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" > 

        <TextView
            style="@style/buttonFont"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/str_base_activity_toolbar_completed" /> 
    </LinearLayout> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Вы лучше код на pastebin.com залили. Ширина не удобная для чтения.

Comment: +1 к совету. А еще покажите лучше проблемный кусок кода, а не весь лайаут. Неплохо было бы картинку ну или там мокап того, что нужно получить и того, что получается на данный момент

Comment: Сейчас нет возможности выложить картинку, а кусок кода выложу внизу своего сообщения

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Замечание** - безусловно не по теме
Вложенные друг в друга `RelativeLayout` это не есть айс... `RelativeLayout` тем и хороши, что нет нужды вкладывать их друг в друга:

> A RelativeLayout is a very powerful
> utility for designing a user interface
> because it can eliminate nested
> ViewGroups

**Замечание** теперь уже по теме
Используйте атрибут `android:layout_below` или `android:layout_below` или `android:layout_above`. [Фтыкать сюда](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html)

Comment: Спасибо, попробую...